# How to Take Value from a specific cell of GridView with autogenerated Columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

the gridview is bound with the database and there are 20 columns in it. now what i wanted to do is to select the values of some of those columns when the Edit button is clicked. Please Help as i dont know how to.

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gv_Data" runat = "server" Font-Size="XX-Small"BackColor="#DEBA84" 
        BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
        CellSpacing="2" onrowcommand="gv_Data_RowCommand">
    <Columns>

    <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button"
    CommandName = "EditRow"
    Text="Edit"/>
    </Columns>



        <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />



    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use foreach loop in your edit button event

```
foreach(GridViewRow gvr in gv_Data){
   TextBox t = gvr.Cells[0].FindControl("TextField1") as TextBox;
   t.Text = "abc";
   DropDownList ddl = gvr.Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
   ddl.SelectedValue = 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to first identify the row for which the edit button was clicked.

You will have to use `RowCommand` event to handle all of this and here is how you can identify the row whenever an edit is clicked.

```
GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
```

Now that you have the row, get the row index like this which will help you get the column details for that particular row :

```
int RowIndex = gvr.RowIndex;
```

After you have the row index, now its time to get the details out of the columns using that index and this :

```
string cId = row.Cells[1].Text;
```

You can use either the index or the column name here between those braces to get the column data that you want. Here, `row` is the `GridViewRow` that we obtained earlier in this answer.

This should give you an idea about how to progress with this.